# How can I tell if my question is used to mark other questions as duplicates?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I'm interested to know if and which questions have been marked duplicates of my questions (there aren't many of them, but I'm curious).

Is there a way to do that (And if not, how about that as a feature)?

Comment: You only have 4 questions so could just visit them all and look at the linked questions sidebar.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I wrote I don't have many questions but still it's nice to be able to see a "report" of these like CRABOLO showed. Having said that, it's a good point to look at the linked questions, so why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: Personally, it was awhile (more than a year) before I realized the "linked questions" were questions linked from the given question, *as well as* questions linking to the given question.

Comment: Linked questions can also be linked by comments

Comment: @Thomas - yes that's true but I am more interested in the cases where the question is specifically used as the target of a duplicate question close.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think I got it right with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366317/search-for-questions-that-were-closed-as-duplicate-to-one-of-your-questions). Just enter your userId and run the query.

```
SELECT pl.PostId AS [Post Link], pl.RelatedPostId AS [Post Link]
FROM PostLinks AS pl
JOIN Posts AS p
ON p.Id = pl.RelatedPostId
WHERE
  p.OwnerUserId = ##yourUserId##
  and p.PostTypeId = 1
  and pl.LinkTypeId = 3
```

It didn't return any results with [your UserId](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366317/search-for-questions-that-were-closed-as-duplicate-to-one-of-your-questions?yourUserId=3887516) so it doesn't look like any of your questions are the duplicate target to any currently  closed as duplicate questions.

I tried running the [query again](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366317/search-for-questions-that-were-closed-as-duplicate-to-one-of-your-questions?yourUserId=106224) with [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)'s UserId and it returned 49 results. Where the duplicate target (BoltClock's question) is the link in the right column, and the duplicate in the left column.

Comment: Does this also work for answers? I rarely ask questions, so I'm more interested in that.

Comment: @Adriaan That one doesn't work for that, but this query should do what you want  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366727/search-for-questions-that-were-closed-as-duplicate-to-a-question-you-have-an-ans